# Delete Files Older Than One year on Linux

Tags: command-line

By the time, many files are still on my system and I don't need them anymore, so how to delete all files that are one year old at least?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it with this command

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +365 -exec rm {} \;
```

Some explain

`/path/to/files*` is the path to the files.

`-mtime` is used to specify the number of days old that the file is. +365 will find files older than 365 days which is one year

`-exec` allows you to pass in a command such as rm.

---

Edit 
Thanks to @Oli note --> you can do it by:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +365 -delete
```

Comment: You should always quote the `{}` in `-exec` (so it reads `-exec rm "{}" \;`). This makes sure that spaces are handled properly... And  you could just use the `-delete` function instead of `-exec`.

Comment: @Oli [**Huh???**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8524066/) (What you have said cannot be right, considering that the shell turns `"{}"` into `{}` before passing it to `find` in the first place; then `find` substitutes for it. Quoting `{}` is suggested in case `{` and `}` themselves may sometimes be treated specially by the shell--which has nothing to do with blank spaces. And often `{}` doesn't have to be quoted. I can't think of any situation, at least when invoking find from a Bourne-style shell, when `{}`, with nothing inside, appearing by itself as an argument, would have to be quoted. Can you?)

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, turns out `find` handles escaping for itself but it's not a bad habit to be in while scripting. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Oli But it doesn't help, even in principle. If `find` didn't handle escaping, `"{}"` would still have the same effect as `{}`--just neither would work, instead of both working. That `{}` and `"{}"` behave the same isn't--and cannot be--due to any special feature of find. Confusing what gets expanded by the shell with what gets expanded by some other program *is* a bad habit. We all make that mistake occasionally, but it's still a mistake--not a best practice. (One might still quote `{}` to help humans see it's not a pattern for brace expansion, but that's unrelated to word splitting.)

Comment: can i use `find .`  if i am on the active directory?